# Send requests to second tomcat node only in case of failure of first node

Tags: apache, tomcat, load-balancing, httpd.conf, mod-jk

I need to have the following setup for an application

Apache HTTP Server
Tomcat Node A
Tomcat Node B

I need to load balance the two tomcat instances in such a way that

-initially all requests should go to nodeA.

-only in case Node A is down, requests should start going to NodeB.

-in no scenario should both nodes be serving the requests at the same time.

I am unable to understand what values should I configure for `lbfactor` for such a setup.

There is a similar question [HTTP Load Balancing - rdirect only if first worker fails using mod_jk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31017740/http-load-balancing-rdirect-only-if-first-worker-fails-using-mod-jk) but it does not have any answers.

Answer (score 0):

You want to mark the 2nd server a a hot standby with status=+H on the ProxyPass line that defines it inside of a balancer.

It will only be used if all other balancer members are offline.